# Wildcard character in MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access, vba, wildcard

I have two tables that I need to query for my report.

The first table is `Test_Cap_Model_1` and second table is `Router`.

I've already added two table in my query and I want to query based on criteria:

```
if [Test_Cap_Model1].[Modell] Like [Router].[TestModel]*
```

Which mean that if field `Model1` in `Test_Cap_Model_1` table contains a value that starts with `testmodel` in `Router` table. I've already tried to insert criteria but it said invalid operator.

[image: query]

I wrote the criteria part like this:

```
[Test_Cap_Model1].[Model] Like [TestModel]%
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
[Test_Cap_Model1].[Model] Like [TestModel] & '%'
```

Comment: it didnt show any value :( i already try to change the position of the table but it also cant retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to concatenate the wildcard operator with the field value (assuming a string valued field of course):

```sql
Test_Cap_Model1.Model like Router.[Test Model] & "*"
```

The use of a percent sign (`%`) as a wildcard operator will only be valid if the database is set to use ANSI-92 syntax, which is not typically the default.

Square brackets surrounding field names are only required if the field names contain spaces, or if you are using reserved words without a table qualifier.

I'm unsure whether the field should be `Test Model` or `TestModel` since this differs between your question description and your screenshot.

Rather than using a cross join per your screenshot, you can alternatively apply the wildcard match to the join criteria, for example:

```sql
select 
    t.model,
    t.1st_pass,
    t.prime,
    r.route
from
    test_cap_model1 t inner join router r on t.model like r.[test model] & "*"
where
    t.retest = 2 and
    t.test_flow = 'Cummulative Yield'
```

Though note that MS Access will not be able to display such joins in the Query Designer and so you'll need to retain SQL view to ensure that the joins are not destroyed by MS Access.

Note the possible typo in your screenshot:

```
'Cummulative Yield'
```

Should perhaps be:

```
'Cumulative Yield'
```

Comment: i already try your suggestion but why my record become so many? its supposed to be 200+ but now its become 45890 ? its like the data had been duplicate.

Comment: i have already edit the code " on t.model like..' to "on r.test model t.model and i got it correct. but its still duplicate certain data. i just want each of model only appear once. do you know how? is it i need to apply 'distinct' ?

Comment: Difficult to advise without knowing your data structure; there is likely to be a one-to-many relationship between records in your tables for the joins used.